# How to change Number Format based on range dynamically?

Tags: excel, vba

i have data in sheet1 starting from A2, i want all data that is in range A2 to have number format, and i want it to be done dynamically..

I will respect any answer.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [reprex]. Your question needs more detail. What number format?

Comment: You really don't need VBA to format a column...

Comment: oh sorry,,,,

I mean, I want to change every data that is in range A2 from "General" to "Number" format.. but I want it to be done dynamically..

Answer (score 0):

looks like i managed to make a code like what i want, is there any other better way than this?

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim LR As Integer

LR = ws.range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        With ws.range(ws.Cells(1, "A"), ws.Cells(LR, "A"))
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            .NumberFormat = "0"
        End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```